# Looking for open-source asp.net intranet / portal / protected site

Tags: asp.net, open-source, portal, intranet, visual-web-developer

I have a website made using Visual Web Developer.  Every attempt I've made at handling databases, or manipulating the ASP.NET configuration manager has failed in frustration.  Consequently, I'm wondering if anybody knows of an open-source, downloadable project I can use for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built my intranet based (and authenticated) website & related database management system based upon the [Contoso University MVC Entity Framework project](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Deviations: I created an intranet project instead of normal web project

web.config items: 
The only items I needed to configure in the web.config file was

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
    <allow roles="DomainName\DomainGroupName" />
    <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

On specific controllers which needed stricter permissions, on the line preceding the ActionResult you can add in an [Authorize] element for specific users or groups

Comment: Hey Mad, thanks for taking the time to post that link, and the amendments to your web.config file.  I'm not smart enough to do this on my own, so hopefully this website can walk me through it.  I appreciate you taking the time to respond!